# Check if set of 10 new rows is unique before adding to table, record with boolean

Tags: php, mysql

So every day, I'm gathering a top 10 list, creating a temporary table **temp**. There is a large table, **timeline**, which aggregates these lists, with the following columns:

```
date, num, id, changed
```

I want to check whether this set in **temp** of 10 books is unique, or whether it's source hasn't been updated and the values are a repeat. I want to capture this in a boolean, *changed*, in **temp** before adding to **timeline**.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but within PHP I've created an array for the previous day and last set added, and compare with the current set, storing the result in a separate array $change_array. I don't know how to add this back into **temp**, i.e. convert this array of 0s and 1s into a column, or add the values to their respective rows in one command. Just for reference, those commands look like this:

```
$last_ten = "SELECT num, asin FROM timeline ORDER BY date DESC, num ASC LIMIT 0,10";
$cur_ten = "SELECT num, asin FROM temp ORDER BY num ASC";
...
for ($ind = 1; $ind <= 10; $ind++) {
    $change_array[$ind] = ($currents[$ind] == $prevs[$ind]) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah that would streamline comparing the arrays, but how would I add that back into the table? I'd prefer not to iterate over the array and add to each row individually...

Comment: Than if you have id-s in the array you can use IN statement in SQL. For example UPDATE timeline set changed=1 where id IN(1,2,3,4,55,99)

Answer (score 0):

Decided just to simplify, using array_intersect as recommended, and if the whole set differs by even one row, then all the rows for that date are marked as being different:

```
$last_ten = "SELECT num, asin FROM timeline t ORDER BY t.date DESC, t.num ASC LIMIT 0,10";
$cur_ten = "SELECT num, asin FROM $table ORDER BY num ASC";

$prevs = array(1 => "", 2 => "", 3 => "", 4 => "", 5 => "", 6 => "", 7 => "", 8 => "", 9 => "",  10 => "");
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($last_ten_res))
    {
        $num = $r['num'];
        $prevs[$num] = $r['asin'];
    }

$currents = array(1 => "", 2 => "", 3 => "", 4 => "", 5 => "", 6 => "", 7 => "", 8 => "", 9 => "",  10 => "");
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($cur_ten_res))
    {
        $num = $r['num'];
        $currents[$num] = $r['asin'];
    }

$different = count(array_intersect($prevs, $currents)) == 10 ? 0 : 1;
$add_change = "ALTER TABLE $table ADD changed INT(1) DEFAULT $different;";
```